# Questions about mass conservation in PDE

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, lebesgue-integral

Let us consider the following PDE:

$$\partial_t{f}(t,x,u)+u\cdot\nabla_xf(t,x,u)+g(x)\cdot\nabla_uf(t,x,u)=0,$$
where $(t,x,u)\in[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a continuous function.

If $f$ is a solution of this PDE in classical sense, the usual proof of the fact that $\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}f(t,x,u)dxdu=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}f(0,x,u)dxdu$ reads as follows:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}f(t,x,u)dxdu=\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}\partial _tf(t,x,u)dxdu=-\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}u\cdot\nabla_xf(t,x,u)dxdu-\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}g(x)\cdot\nabla_uf(t,x,u)dxdu.$$
By using integration by parts and asuming an appropiate decay of $f$, we deduce that $\frac{d}{dt}\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}f(t,x,u)dxdu=0.$

However, there are some details of this proof that I don't understand:

1. Why can we iterate the time derivative in the first step?
2. Is this property still true if we consider weak solutions?, that is if $f$ verifies:
   $$\displaystyle\int_{0}^T\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}f(t,x,u)\left[\partial _t\psi(t,x,u)+u\cdot\nabla_x\psi(t,x,u)+g(x)\cdot\nabla_u\psi(t,x,u)\right]dxdu+\displaystyle\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}}f(0,x,u)\psi(0,x,u)dxdu=0,\\\forall\psi \in C^1([0,T]\times \mathbb{R}^{2d}) \text{ with } \operatorname{supp}\psi\subset [0,T[\times C \text{ and } C \text{ compact in }\mathbb{R}^{2d}$$

Any help about this questions will be welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "iterate"?  The property holds for a weak solution provided $t \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2d}} |f(t,u,x)| \, du \, dx$ is a bounded function.

Comment: When I say "iterate" I mean why  we can introduce the partial derivative into the integral

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: As with your second question, one is allowed to "differentiate under the integral sign" provided $f$ is a nice enough weak solution.  With these kinds of computations (in the study of PDEs), the thing to do is to convince yourself if $f$ were smooth and compactly supported, then the computation would work.

Comment: But, what happens if $f$ is not $C^1$ in time variable?,  don't we introduce the concept of weak solution precisely to overcome that obstacle?